# Where was this Grace Hopper/Univac photo taken?

Tags: history, identify-this-computer

Here is a photo of a Univac I with four individuals. According to [Artifact Details](https://www.computerhistory.org/collections/catalog/102741216) at the Computer History Museum's web page with an extremely similar photo (perhaps a shot a few moments earlier/later):

> Date: 1957
>
> Description: Image shows operator's console of Univac I computer and four programmers. From left to right, Donald Cropper, K. C. Krishnan, Grace Hopper, and Norman Rothberg.
>
> Lot Number: X7424.2015

The image can also be found at

- Flickr: [public.resource.org](https://www.flickr.com/photos/publicresourceorg/493885707)
- Wikiquote: [File:Grace Hopper and UNIVAC.jpg](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/File:Grace_Hopper_and_UNIVAC.jpg) (full and cropped)
- Twitter: [IEEE History Center](https://twitter.com/ieeehistory/status/968200097698742272)
- WW2DB: [Grace Hopper](https://ww2db.com/person_bio.php?person_id=1061) (also [here](https://ww2db.com/image.php?image_id=27392))

Is it possible to know where this photo was taken? There couldn't have been very many Univac I computers that Grace Hopper would have been photographed with, <s>and that distinctive-looking sunburst logo (watermark?) in the upper-left corner may be a clue as well.</s> That's a [non-starter](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9040/where-was-this-grace-hopper-univac-photo-taken/9049#comment28570_9040).

---

[image]

[Source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/archive/3/37/20120604182257%21Grace_Hopper_and_UNIVAC.jpg)

Comment: In this case I've used the `identify-this-computer` tag to identify this particular unit and its location, rather than just the make/model.

Comment: I just found this, possibly helpful towards an answer: https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_086_004_014?solr_nav%5Bid%5D=a2ac56a76ac45b595a60&solr_nav%5Bpage%5D=0&solr_nav%5Boffset%5D=9

Comment: Don't know where the photo was taken, but that looks like a Commodore 64 on the desk.

Comment: I'll bet it's more accurate to say that the Commodore 64 resembles the Univac, considering the timeline of the creation of each.

Comment: I'm not sure who's voting to close this as off-topic, but it seems on-topic to me. Care to explain your vote?

Comment: The watermark is the logo of the [Smithsonian Institution](https://www.si.edu/), a group of museums and research facilities administered by the U.S. government and is not part of the original photo.

Comment: That may be the Remington-Rand (later Sperry) Univac, mentioned in https://books.google.com/books?id=m465BQAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=norman+rothberg+univac&source=bl&ots=q5UWC_vyWT&sig=ACfU3U0MqolRXJqaSb3KXNIHn2kL6UhOcA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi67_LV2prgAhWSMX0KHVCpC5EQ6AEwCXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=norman%20rothberg%20univac&f=false -

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I don't know why either. This is about as Retro as it gets!

Comment: @manassehkatz I'd mentioned [Sperry Corporation, UNIVAC Division › Grace Hopper demonstrating COBOL at Programming Department](https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_086_004_014?solr_nav%5Bid%5D=a2ac56a76ac45b595a60&solr_nav%5Bpage%5D=0&solr_nav%5Boffset%5D=9) in my [comment](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9040/where-was-this-grace-hopper-univac-photo-taken/9049#comment28539_9040) above.

Comment: @Blrfl it looked quite familliar but I couldn't place it, thanks. I've updated the question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I voted to close this because it's not about computing? It's about a photograph. The question doesn't seem to be about computers.

Comment: @Wilson When the photograph shows an old computer, the question can't be off-topic. That is a nonsense argument. If you state your questions in words instead of pictures, (what we normally do), the question wouldn't be closed "because it's about words".

Comment: Iust checked the rules. Nothing about it being ok to ask about where a picture is taken. On the other hand, you could see this as identifying a specific machine... Might be time to consider rewriting the help text, since (at least to me) this type of questions are interesting

Comment: @tofro Certainly it can be off-topic. Look: "Someone took a picture ages ago which has a computer in it. Who took the picture and where?" is not a question about retrocomputing. Is it?

Comment: @Wilson I seem to remember quite a number of your own questions that could be closed with similar reasoning like "That's no question about computers but rather business decisions". I think if it's about computers (and this photo definitely is), we're fine.(BTW: The question doesn't ask for the photographer. Don't know where you got that from. It's quite clear the OP wants to identify the specific machine that was photographed. And, given the very small number of Univacs built, that's a legit question. I agree that if the photo would show a C64, it wouldn't quite be on-topic)

Comment: @Wilson I'd thought about topicality before posting; I decided that this particular computer, with this particular set of programmers were sufficiently notable, and sufficiently relevant in the development of computing during the 'retro' years. There are always edge cases in SE topicality that need to be considered on their individual merits and contribution to the site. In this case Wikipedia mentions that only 46 Univac I computers ever were built *in toto*.

Comment: @tofro I interpreted the "where" to mean "which facility", as apparently manassehkatz did, answering "DOD, and likely the Navy". I did not mean the photographer! Okay, well I have an opinion about it, so I voted. Feel free to submit your own votes.

Comment: @UncleBod I've tried; nobody's willing to help write it, and I'm not confident enough in my assumptions as to what's on- and off-topic to unilaterally speak for everyone. [It's here if you're interested.](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/634/278)

Comment: A question about Rear-Admiral Hopper and a computer is *surely* in the realm of retrocomputing.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, this picture was taken 1960. Not sure whom to believe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper#/media/File:Grace_Hopper_and_UNIVAC.jpg

Comment: Note of the two new residential colleges at Yale is named after Grace Hopper. I once saw her speak at an ACM conference. I recall she held a length of wire and explained it was a picosecond - the length it took electricity to propagate in one picosecond. See also
https://news.yale.edu/2019/03/26/math-not-computer-science-was-grace-hoppers-first-language
and
https://president.yale.edu/biography-grace-murray-hopper

Comment: Another image from a slightly different perspective: https://blog.adafruit.com/2014/05/19/grace-hopper-and-univac-computing-history-womeninstem/

Comment: @snips-n-snails excellent find, thank you! I love Lady Ada's posts and videos in general as well.

Comment: @DrSheldon [So let it be written. So let it be done.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3bQnxlHZsjY)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Before I give my guess, let's see what we have so far:
Apart from the picture links in the question, we also have this link [Grace Hopper demonstrating COBOL at Programming Department](https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_086_004_014?solr_nav%5Bid%5D=a2ac56a76ac45b595a60&solr_nav%5Bpage%5D=0&solr_nav%5Boffset%5D=9) (Thank you @uoho).
Most links places the picture as circa 1960 or 1957 and several also mentions COBOL.
From the WW2DB link in the question, we can see that in this time frame Grace Hopper was working for Univac. The link above even places the picture at "Programming Department", the picture originated from Sperry Rand (Corporation), Univac Division and dates it as 1957-06, ie June 1957.

The date is still a small problem. Even if I believe Hagley Digital Archives more than Wikipedia (Museum Curators normally don't give exact date without good backup evidence) it was impossible to have a COBOL class at that date, since COBOL was designed 1959 [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBOL). So, either is the date wrong, or the COBOL reference a bit wrong. (It could have been during the work that led up to COBOL).

All of the people in the picture are also in some other pictures from [Hagley Digital Archives](https://digital.hagley.org/islandora/search?type=dismax&islandora_solr_search_navigation=1&f%5B0%5D=mods_name_corporate_org_namePart_ms%3ASperry%5C%20Rand%5C%20%5C%28Corporation%5C%29.%5C%20Univac%5C%20Division) (you might need to search around a bit). This makes me think that all 4 people were at the time part of Grace Hoppers team at Sperry Univac.

So, my best guess (until any more proof gets up) is that it was taken at Sperry Univac, at their "school room". Time somewhere between 1957 and 1960.

---

DrSheldon updates: **This answer is correct.  It was taken in June 1957 at Sperry-UNIVAC.**

The original physical photograph is [in possession at the Hagley Museum](https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_086_004_014) in the Sperry-UNIVAC collection, box 86, folder 4.  It is an 8 x 10 in physical photograph., and lacks the Smithsonian watermark.  (The Hagley is a Smithsonian affiliate, which is perhaps how the Smithsonian acquired a digital copy.)  The Hagley documents the date as `1957-06`, which is June 1957.

I do agree with UncleBod that the Hagley title for the photograph ("Grace Hopper demonstrating COBOL at Programming Department") does not fit with the timeline of COBOL.  But all of the other details are consistent.

Three of the four persons (Hopper, Rothberg, and Cropper) appear in [another Sperry-UNIVAC photo](https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_086_004_018).  It is also dated 1957, but seems to be a different room than the question photo:

> Left to right: William Finley, **Norman Rothberg**, James McGarvey, Mary Lou Greene, **Grace Hopper**, and **Donald Cropper**.

[image: Hopper with Rothberg and Cropper]

The remaining person (Krishnan) appears with Hopper in [a similar photo](https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_040_072_11):

> Left to right: **K.C. Krishnan**, Laura Yu, Donald Sullivan, George Schmalen Berger, Frederick Tweed, **Grace Hopper**, and Frank Lagan.

[image: Hopper with Krishnan]

It's also worth mentioning that [Hopper appears at her Sperry-UNIVAC desk](https://digital.hagley.org/1985261_086_004_068) with the same (or similar) clothing to the question's picture:

[image: Hopper at her desk]

All of the people (including Hopper) appear to be Sperry-UNIVAC employees.  Other than Hopper, none appeared at the [May 1959 CODASYL meeting](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4640600) which drafted COBOL.  It is therefore reasonable to conclude that the picture was taken at Sperry-UNIVAC.

Answer (score 5):

> "So when seeking employment I applied to [Grace Hopper's] Automatic
>   Programming Department at Remington-Rand Univac and was employed
>   started in June 1959.
>
> "The day of reckoning was in December 1960 when the CODASYL
>   dignitaries showed up one day at RCA in Camden and the next day in
>   Univac in Philadelphia.
>
> "During the spring of 1961 [we] moved from the primitive facilities at
>   19th and Allegheny Avenue (an old dusty and dirty Exide battery
>   warehouse) to a new luxurious building in Blue Bell, Pennsylvania.

Source: Harold "Bud" Lawson (inventor of the pointer variable). "[Experiences and Reflections](http://dl.ifip.org/db/series/ifip/ifip387/Lawson12.pdf)." (The photo in the .pdf file is also located [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Univac_I_Census_dedication.jpg) and [here](https://www.npr.org/2011/06/19/137280862/the-first-supercomputer-vs-the-desk-set).)

So my guess (just a guess) is that the photo was taken at 19th Street and Allegheny Avenue, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania. (One remaining building of the Exide complex [still stands](https://hiddencityphila.org/2014/01/a-long-battery-life-on-north-phillys-allegheny-avenue/), but the Remington-Rand Univac buildings south of Allegheny and north of the tracks appear to have all been demolished.)

I think everyone in the photo has passed away by now: Donald Cropper (b. 1939?) in 2011, Kalpathi C. Krishnan (b. 1924) in 2002, Grace Hopper (b. 1906) in 1992, and Norman Rothberg (b. 1935?) in 2003.

A few years ago, the Smithsonian posted on Facebook [asking](https://www.facebook.com/SmithsonianInstitutionArchives/posts/were-on-a-research-mission-for-the-the-white-house-cto-this-is-a-photo-from-the-/939129822778159/) for the identities of the people in the photo. They might be a lead for information about the photo's location, in addition to Professor Lawson if anyone knows how to contact him.

Comment: Thank you for writing such a helpful and informed answer!

Answer (score 4):

Could be "anywhere". But my guess would be a US government facility, more likely DOD, and most likely of all Navy. In addition to Admiral Grace Hopper, Donald Cropper [according to this obituary](https://obituaries.pressherald.com/obituaries/mainetoday-pressherald/obituary.aspx?n=donald-l-cropper&pid=190381626&fhid=16468) if I have the right one, was in the Navy and then Marines. So my first guess would be the 1953 installation at David W. Taylor Model Basin as listed in the [the Wikipedia Univac I article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_I) and sourced from [this newsletter](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/onr/Digital_Computer_Newsletter/Digital_Computer_Newsletter_V05N03_Jul53.pdf)

But really that is just a guess. The Army and Air Force had systems as well, and Grace Hopper & Donald Cropper might have been sent over to those systems to help get things running.

Comment: Unfortunately, in 1957, Grace Hopper seems to have been [working at Sperry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Hopper#UNIVAC), as their "director of automatic programming" which meant compilers, for UNIVAC machines. So she might well have visited any site with a UNIVAC I.

Comment: @JohnDallman I'd be happy to be proven wrong by someone with more definite information. As I said, "just a guess". But perhaps enough to point someone else in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe the Pentagon, which is where the May 28-29, 1959 CODASYL meeting was held.